# library config doesn't support I/O in IAR

Tags: c++, fstream, iar

I'm new to IAR and I am just configuring a C++ project but I'm surprised with this error:
`Fatal Error[Pe035]: #error directive: "This library configuration does not support file I/O, either use another existing library configuration or define a new and rebuild the library."` in the fstream file (which is Read Only in my case).

here are the lines of code that cause the error:

```
#if !_DLIB_FILE_DESCRIPTOR
  #error "This library configuration does not support file I/O, either use \
          another existing library configuration or define a new and rebuild \
          the library."
#endif
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

File streams are not enabled by default.

Go to your project options (`Project > Options...` menu), select `General Options` category and `Library Configuration` tab. From `Library` dropdown select `Full`.

Note that this simply enables file streams in library. When you use file streams with C-SPY debugger (and semihosting enabled, I think) it opens files on your computer. In order to read files from your embedded device memory, you need to also implement DLIB low level I/O interface. Read IAR manual on how to do that.